# How to change the configuration path to pick a different JAVA executable?

Tags: command-line, java, eclipse, environment-variables

I have a *nix VM allocated me running CEL6.x version. The JVM pre-built in the image is 1.6 version (which is located under /usr/bin).

Now I need to have Eclipse in the VM. I have a Eclipse executable which needs JVM 1.8 or above.

Unfortunately, i dont have necessary permission to install any software on the VM.

Fortunately, discovered that in one of the mounted path /*abc*/bin, java-1.8.0_91 is present.

Now I need a way, when we execute *java*, the one present under /*abc*/bin (Java 1.8) should be picked rather than the default one present under /usr/bin (Java 1.6).

Any environmental variable i need to change to make this working? Say, JAVA_HOME or something like that.

Comment: "CEL6.x version" doesn't sound like Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The update-alternatives command will let you pick which version of Java to use:

```
user@host:~$ update-alternatives --config java
```

While it's generally not a good idea to change it manually (use the command above), you can observe that the actual java binary used when you type "java" is controlled by a series of symbolic links:

```
user@host:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
user@host:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan  3 09:03 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
user@host:~$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Jan  3 09:03 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: This allows - for the <name> group and ask the user to select which one to use.
When i try this it says, "update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java"
Since i dont have an alternate version made available.
So how would i do that?
I tried using --install and also --set option. But none of them helped in achieving what i needed.